# Referring to a CSS attribute inside the same class

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to darken each button when you hover over them and I have no idea how to refer to the original color value in the `:hover` attribute.

```
//buttons.scss

//Define the colors
$tumblr-color: #35455C;
$twitter-color: #5AB6FC;

//Put these colors into classes
.btn-tumblr
{
    color: $tumblr-color;
}

.btn-twitter
{
    color: $twitter-color;
}

//Add the "darkens when hovered over" attribute
.btn-tumblr,
.btn-twitter
{
    &:hover
    {
        color: darken(/*ATTRIBUTE OF THE ORIGINAL COLOR HERE*/, 20%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way yet as of this writing, but another way to approach organizing your code to achieve the same end result (keeping things DRY) would be:

```
//buttons.scss

//Define the colors
$tumblr-color: #35455C;
$twitter-color: #5AB6FC;
$colors: $tumblr-color, $twitter-color;

//Mixins
@mixin thedarkening($color) {
  color: darken($color, 20%);
}

@for $i from 1 through length($colors) {
    .btn-#{$i} {
        color: nth($colors, $i);
        &:hover {
            @include thedarkening(nth($colors, $i));
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/b9z05ms6/2/)

Caveat: requires you to change your classes to `.btn-1`, `.btn-2`, so on.

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the hover style inside each class, like this:

```
//Define the colors
$tumblr-color: #35455C;
$twitter-color: #5AB6FC;

.btn-tumblr {
    color: $tumblr-color;
    &:hover {
        color: darken($tumblr-color, 20%);
    }
}

.btn-twitter {
    color: $twitter-color;
    &:hover {
        color: darken($twitter-color, 20%);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can mimic the darken effect using opacity.

```
// Mimic the darken effect on hover

.btn-tumblr,
.btn-twitter {
  opacity: .7;
  &:hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```